# Wrap text round brackets

Tags: formatting

I want to accomplish this effect with LaTeX:

[image]

I have a slight idea of how to do that using \left{ and \right} on math mode but I’m not sure. If there’s a package that helps to do that, coding would be much easier and code would be much more beautiful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another possibility is to use the `array` environment:

```
He is being
{\arraycolsep=0pt $\left\{
 \begin{array}{l} \mbox{a nuisance}\\ \mbox{naughty} \end{array}
 \right\}$}
again.
```

the `\arraycolsep` has to be localized, otherwise it will apply to the entire document from that point on.  if you are already using the `amsmath` package, you can use `\text` instead of `\mbox`.

Answer (score 5):

Fairly simple

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\begin{document}
He is being $\left\{\parbox{4.5em}{a nuisance\\nauggty}\right\}$ again
\end{document}
```

memoir is not relevant, just the default class in my editor

Answer (score 3):

I would write something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\multilines#1{$\left\{\vcenter{\vbox{\parse@arg#1\\\parse@arg\@nil}}\right\}$}
\def\parse@arg#1\\#2\@nil{\hbox{#1}\ifx\parse@arg#2\else\def\next{\parse@arg#2\@nil}\expandafter\next\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
He is being \multilines{a nuisance\\naughty} again.

\TeX{} is \multilines{great\\powerful\\sooo easy}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's two TikZ solutions!

[image: TikZ bracketing text]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\bracketwrap}[2][]{%
\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[anchor=east,align=left,left delimiter=\{,right delimiter=\},#1] (a) at (0,.5ex) {#2};}

\newcommand{\altbracketwrap}[2][]{%
\tikz[baseline=0pt] {\node[anchor=east,align=left,#1] (a) at (0,.5ex) {#2}; \draw[line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4},line cap=round] (a.north east) -- (a.south east); \draw[line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4},line cap=round] (a.south west) -- (a.north west);}}


\begin{document}

He is being \bracketwrap{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \bracketwrap[inner sep=0pt]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \bracketwrap[inner sep=10pt]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \bracketwrap[text=red]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \bracketwrap[align=center]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \bracketwrap[align=right]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \altbracketwrap{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \altbracketwrap[inner sep=0pt]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \altbracketwrap[inner sep=10pt]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \altbracketwrap[text=red]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \altbracketwrap[align=center]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

He is being \altbracketwrap[align=right]{a nuisance\\naughty} again

\end{document}
```

The `matrix` library in TikZ defines a couple of keys `left delimiter` and `right delimiter` which specify left and right delimiters.  These can be applied to almost any node, not just matrices.  The first set of examples uses these.

However, I find that *sometimes* I can see the pieces that the extensible braces are made from (look at the third example of the image above), so the second set actually draws the braces using the `decorations.pathreplacing` library.  You lose the nice tapering at the ends and middle of the braces, but at least the braces are continuous.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\options}[1]
{\(\left\{\mbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        #1
    \end{tabular}}%
\right\}\)}
\begin{document}
He is being $\left\{\mbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} a nuisance \\ naughty
\end{tabular}}\right\}$ again.

It can be used with \options{ more \\ many \\ lots of }
alternatives!
\end{document}
```

Uses `tabular` inside `mbox`, inside display-math containing auto-sizing brackets. I used `@{}l@{}` as column specifier, to suppress some spacing.